# Spring Cloud Config Server - empty array for refreshed keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-cloud-config

I have a spring cloud config server as in this [repo](https://github.com/Ali-Wassouf/springcloudconfigserver)
And a client in this [repo](https://github.com/Ali-Wassouf/spring-cloud-client)
following is my POM file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ali.wassouf.spring.cloud.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloud-config-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cloud-config-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-monitor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.yml of the config server

```yaml
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        monitor:
          github:
            enabled: true
          gitee:
            enabled: true
        git:
          password: ${PASSWORD}
          username: ${USERNAME}
          uri: https://github.com/Ali-Wassouf/springcloudconfigrepo
          search-paths: '{application}'
```

The config repo that this server serves has the following structure

```
.
+-- serviceA
|   +-- application-dev.properties
|   +-- application-prod.properties
+-- serviceB
|   +-- application-dev.properties
|   +-- application-prod.properties
```

I have a webhook configured for the config repo.
I also have a rabbitMQ image running locally.

When I push my changes to the config repo I get these line on the console

```
o.s.c.c.monitor.PropertyPathEndpoint     : Refresh for: *:prod
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c943d8f: startup date [Mon Nov 23 18:55:19 CET 2020]; root of context hierarchy
o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on [class org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration$RetryConfiguration]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain annotation attribute value for public abstract java.lang.Class[] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass.value()
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$aacb9e64] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7d2d9a8f: startup date [Mon Nov 23 18:55:20 CET 2020]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c943d8f
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 1.515 seconds (JVM running for 31.102)
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7d2d9a8f: startup date [Mon Nov 23 18:55:20 CET 2020]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c943d8f
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2c943d8f: startup date [Mon Nov 23 18:55:19 CET 2020]; root of context hierarchy
o.s.cloud.bus.event.RefreshListener      : Received remote refresh request. Keys refreshed []
```

The array of Refreshed keys is empty
I tried changing to an older version of Spring Boot/Cloud, as well as a newer version, but this didn't work.

I have seen questions similar to my case but non of them had any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the client, it's missing spring cloud config as well as the dependency management for spring cloud
adding this dependency to the client code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and adding this dependency management as well

```
<dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
               <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
               <type>pom</type>
               <scope>import</scope>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.yml` you have defined `spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths` configuration key. However, looking at [this doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html) from spring official documentation, the key seems to should have been *`searchPaths`* (snakeCase, no dash).
Hence, I think your `application.yml` should look like this:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  application:
    name: cloud-config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        monitor:
          github:
            enabled: true
          gitee:
            enabled: true
        git:
          password: ${PASSWORD}
          username: ${USERNAME}
          uri: https://github.com/Ali-Wassouf/springcloudconfigrepo
          searchPaths: '{application}'
```

Comment: I can fetch properties manually by calling '/actuator/refresh' from the server in the client, I just don't see an update in the client when the github hook send a POST to '/monitor' in the server