# How do you get passwords from maven settings or gradle properties into your java/kotlin code at build time?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, gradle, passwords

You aren't supposed to put passwords or api keys into your code.  Definitely don't check them into source control!  Both maven and gradle have ways to store private stuff in your home folder and incorporate passwords at build time.  People use this to deploy to Maven Central/Sonatype.  But wouldn't this be the perfect place to store passwords that get used in your code?  Like the database password or keystore password?

Is there a way to incorporate something into your code at build time so your java code could say something like:

```java
  private static final String myPw = "$$maven.settings.servers.server[ossrh].password$$";
```

So that your build tool would substitute it on the fly so it ends up in your bytecode, but not in your source code, or source repository?  A Java or Kotlin annotation perhaps?

Comment: This is typically reached by reading settings from some properties file in java code at runtime, but this file is processed during build phase, with variable substitutions you described in the sample.

Comment: For such cases a thing like https://www.vaultproject.io/ are a good choice for example because deployment. And no it's not a good idea to use references on your settings.xml cause it's only available during build time but usually not at run time...

Comment: Also things like spring cloud config as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64973947/296328. are a good choice as well...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create file during compilation

```kotlin
tasks.withType<ProcessResources> {
    doLast {
        File("$buildDir/resources/main/build.properties").writeText("""
            version=${someVariable}
        """.trimIndent())
    }
}
```

Step 2: Read during Runtime

```kotlin
object BuildInfo {
    val VERSION: String

    init {
        // build.properties file will be generated by gradle
        val buildProps = Properties()
        buildProps.load(ClassPathResource("build.properties").inputStream)
        VERSION = buildProps["version"] as String
    }
}
```

You can access this via `BuildInfo.VERSION`

Comment: OK, but if you don't check build.properties into source control, how does it get deployed?  Do you do that separately from your application?  Build another build.properties into your docker container that you also don't put into source control?  I was hoping it would get compiled into the code.

Comment: If you are using Docker containers, then it should be fairly easy: Just use environment variables via System.getenv(String)